# Can not retrieve DropdownList value in model using mvc & ado.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net, html.dropdownlistfor

I am sending selectedlist to view using ViewBag. Here is the get method that i pass through ViewBag

```
public List<Dept> GetDept()
 {
    connection();
    List<Dept> deptList = new List<Dept>();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Sp_GetDept", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    //Bind EmpModel generic list using dataRow     
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        deptList.Add(
            new Dept
            {
                DeptId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DeptId"]),
                Name = Convert.ToString(dr["Name"])
            }
       );
    }
    return deptList;
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    DeptRepo repo = new DeptRepo();
    ViewBag.Dept = new SelectList(repo.GetDept(), "DeptId", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

**View Code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dept, "Department", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Dept", null, "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dept, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Student model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Roll { get; set; }

    public int DeptId { get; set; }

    public virtual Dept Dept { get; set; }
}
```

post method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Student std)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                StudentRepo repo = new StudentRepo();

                repo.AddStudent(std);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

In post method dropdownlist id value found null in student object.
Can anybody tell me how i can retrieve foreignkey Id using mvc and ado.net.
Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For What property of the Student object ? Your property name should match with your element name. How does your HttpPost action looks like ?

Comment: I add all code as you want. what is the wrong in this code.. how can i retrieve foreign key data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code,

```
@Html.DropDownList("Dept", null, "--Select--", 
                                 htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

will generate HTML markup for a SELECT element with name attribute value set to `Dept`

```
<select class="form-control" id="Dept" name="Dept">
   <option value="">--Select--</option>
</select>
```

Since you are using the `Student` class as your httppost action method parameter, for model binding to properly map the selected option value to `DeptId` property of the Student object, you need to make sure that your select element name is also `DeptId`

If your view is strongly typed to the `Student` class, you can use `DropDownListFor` helper method

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.DeptId, ViewBag.Dept as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
                           "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Or**

You can use `DropDownList` method and give `DeptId` as the first param (name of the control) and explicitly specify the collection to use for building the options as the second param.

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeptId", ViewBag.Dept as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, 
                    "--Select--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This will render the SELECT element with name attribute value set to `DeptId` and when the form is submitted, model binder will be able to use the selected option value to set it to the `DeptId` property of the `Student` object(which is your httppost action method parameter)

Comment: Thank you for your help.